# LINQ group by with multiple fields and aggregate function

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to make a query in LINQ translating the following T-SQL query:

```
select b.crs, 
       d.epg, 
       d.m, 
       Count (a.sq_rea) as qt 
from t_aaaa a with (nolock) 
     join t_bbbb b with (nolock) on a.crs = b.crs 
     join t_cccc c with (nolock) on a.spr = c.spr and c.rsp = 1 
     join v_dddd d with (nolock) on c.epg = d.epg  
Where a.st = 5 
group by b.crs, d.epg, d.m
```

However, I cannot use the aggregate function like this:

```
   var llstData = (from a in lobjaaaaDao.list()
                   join b in lobjbbbbDao.list() on a.p equals b.p
                   join c in lobjcccc.listar() on a.u equals c.u
                   from d in lobjddddDao.list()
                   where a.w == d.w &&
                         a.st.Equals(5) &&
                         d.Indent == false
                   group a by new { b.xxxx, c.yyyy, c.zzzz } into grp
                   select new 
                   { 
                     grp.Key.xxxx, 
                     grp.Key.yyyy, 
                     grp.Key.zzzz, 
                     total = a.kkkk.Count() // ERROR ON THIS LINE
                   }
                   ).ToList();
```

I am getting this error:

> The name a does not exist in th current context

How can I fix the error?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Oh. I see it now.  Hang on, let me edit your OP so it's more obvious.  brb.

Comment: Edited.  Also, just a thought... personally when I have queries (like yours) that I have working in SQL but can't get working in LINQ, I just leave the query in SQL. You don't HAVE to use LINQ. You can still use the t-sql query and get back the same `List<>` you are looking for.  LINQ is great, until it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last select statement the only parameter from the query you are accessible to is `grp`; where each group is [IGrouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=netframework-4.8); each group is represented by a key and an `IEnumerable` which is in your case : `IEnumerable<a>`. Having said that; you can replace the line `total = a.kkkk.Count()` with `total = grp.SelectMany(v=> v.kkkk).Count()` OR `total = grp.Sum(a => a.kkkk.Count())` to resolve the issue. 
This way `total` represents the summation of `kkkk` counts in each a in the group.

Comment: No it's not a `KeyValuePair` is a `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` which is a `IEnumerable<TElement>` and has a `TKey` `Key` property.  So there is no `Value` property.

Comment: Finally I don't see the reason to do a `SelectMany` here it's already grouped, so the count shoud just be on rows where the `sq_rea` is not null.  `grp.Count(a => a.sq_rea != null);`

Comment: @juharr from the question the total is calculated from the count of kkkk which is a property on the object a, which why I assumed that the OP needs the summation of the count of kkkk from each item in the group. => It can be replaced by grp.Sum(a => a.kkkk.Count())

Comment: `group a by... into grp` means that `grp` is a collection of `a` rows.  Maybe the `kkkk` in the Linq is equivalent to the `sq_rea` in the SQL since they do seem to have a number of other name differences.